# Python mechannize 'NoneType object has no attribute 'click()' with br.submit(name=s)

Tags: python, mechanize

what i'm trying to do is automate my browsing tasks using python mechanize
there are four buttons with different names in the html form. I've selected the form using command `br.select_form(nr=0)`. Now

```
s='NameofButton1'
br.submit(name=s)
```

is working good. But as i have to click on all the four buttons so i.m using for loop and the code goes like this

```
sBegin='NameofButton'
l=['1','2','3','4']
for item in l:
    s=sBegin+item
    br.submit(name=s)
```

is not working and giving error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you submit the fist button, your browser state will be redirected to result page.

so i suggest before you begin to submit your form, you should reopen the initial page where you can find those buttons

```
sBegin='NameofButton'
l=['1','2','3','4']
for item in l:
    s=sBegin+item
    br.open("url to initial page")
    br.submit(name=s)
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!!
it worked after putting br.select_form() after br.open("url to initial page")